# Boost::optional<bool> dereference

Tags: c++, boost, boolean, option-type, boost-optional

I am reviewing some code and have something like this:

```
boost::optional<bool> isSet = ...;
... some code goes here...
bool smthelse = isSet ? *isSet : false;
```

So my question is, is the last line equivalent to this:

```
bool smthelse = isSet;
```

Comment: `bool smthelse = isSet.get_value_or(false);` might be easier to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the table:

```
boost::optional<bool> isSet | none | true | false |
----------------------------|------|------|-------|
isSet ? *isSet : false;     | false| true | false |
isSet                       | false| true | true  |
```

As you can see difference in the last column, where `isSet` has been assigned the boolean value `false`.

Alternatively, you can use `isSet.get_value_or(false);`.

Answer (score 4):

No they're not equivalent.

`isSet ? *isSet : false;` means if `isSet` contains a value then get the value, otherwise returns `false`.

---

<sup>BTW: `bool smthelse = isSet;` won't work because `operator bool` is declared as `explicit`.</sup>

Comment: I mean, in which case the result will be different?

Comment: @EduardRostomyan When `isSet` contains a boolean value, but the value is false.

Comment: in that case the value of smthelse will be false as well, isnt it?

Comment: @EduardRostomyan You mean `isSet` or `*isSet`? They're different things.